How do I get postcss to rebuild on css changes
I am trying to get this frontend to rebuild whenever a css module has a change. I can get the build to trigger when we make changes to a css file but it doesn't seem to be writing over any css files (no changes happen in our /dist)
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "find src -name '*.module.css' -exec sh -c 'npx postcss \"$1\" -o \"dist/${1#src/}\"' _ {} \\;",
    "dev:build": "pnpm build:css && pnpm copy-files && tsc",
    "copy-files": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.css src/**/*.module.css.json dist/",
    "assets:deploy": "tsc && pnpm build:css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/**/*.module.css --dir dist --watch",
    "watch:ts": "tsc --watch",
    "assets:watch": "pnpm -r --parallel run watch:css & pnpm -r --parallel run watch:ts",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist"
  },

when we build our project we run pnpm dev:build followed by assets:watch
so I've tried a few things and this is where I'm currently at
what is the simplest way to tsc --watch along with watching any changes to src/**/*.module.css?
what I am stumped on is that anything under /src/components seems to not have a problem with building or hot reloading but anything under /src/pages does. There are no special includes for components or ignores for pages. Everything in the configs has the format src/**/*.module.css
like my tsconfig.json is this
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.frontend.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}


and this is the ../../tsconfig.frontend.json, it just has some super basic settings
  "include": ["packages/@s5/**/src/**/*", "packages/@s5-uis/**/src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Projects */
    "composite": false /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */,

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "es6" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,

    /* JavaScript Support */
    "allowJs": true /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */,
    "checkJs": false /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */,

    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]
  }
}

